# Use RxJs to create HttpRequest queue in Angular2+ interceptors

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, interceptor, subject

I am using interceptors in Angular5 to add an `Authorization` header to each request. The tokens coming from the backend can expire though, in which case a token refresh must occur. If multiple `HttpRequest<any>` come in at the same time, I have no way of making them queue up, so multiple unauthorized requests will be made, and multiple `401` responses will come back from the server, until finally one of the token refreshes completes and the remaining requests can try again. At the moment this is taking about 3 failed attempts per request, until one of them can finally succeed. Current implementation:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private refreshInProgress: boolean = false;

    constructor(private injector: Injector, private router: Router) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `${this.injector.get(AuthService).getAccessToken()}`
            }
        });

        return next.handle(request).catch((error: any) => {
            if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                switch(error.status) {
                    case 401:
                        if(!this.refreshInProgress) {
                            this.refreshInProgress = true;
                            this.injector.get(AuthService).getRefreshToken().subscribe(
                                (success: boolean) => {
                                    if(!success) {
                                        this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                            return this.intercept(request, next);
                        } else {
                            return this.intercept(request, next).delay(700);
                        }
                    default:
                        return Observable.throw(error);
                }
            }
            return Observable.throw(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            this.refreshInProgress = false;
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, the only option I know of is adding a `refreshInProgress` boolean to try and stop the additional requests from going out immediately, and instead trying to make them wait 700 milliseconds before trying again. This hasn't been a great solution, but its passable.

What I think I would like to do is create an `unauthorizedRequestQueue` of maybe a `BehaviorSubject<HttpRequest<any>>`, and then if a `401` has gone out, make subsequent `HttpRequest`s queue up until the first call returns with the refresh token. However, I am still very green with the RxJs library, and have not been able to figure out how to do something like that.

I was hoping the SO community could push me in the right direction as to how I would implement such functionality. Or maybe there is some other better way of doing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sync simple pattern like the following, you also specify how many times you want to retry. Not much need for an interceptor in this use case

```
header={'Authorization':...}
auth() {
  // catch the unauth error and switch to refresh token 
  return this.http.get(authUrl).catch((response: Response) => { 
     return this.http.get(refreshTokenUrl)
            // direct to refresh token call 
           .do(newToken=>this.header['Authorization']=newToken)
           // throw so it can repeat the auth process
           .mapTo(Observable.throw('not yet done')
  }).retry()
 }
```

Comment: The initial login token for the user typically does not throw an exception, and I will only know that the token has timed out if a given call returns a `401`. Since the interceptor is adding the auth token on each call, it is the place where the `401` would first be reported to the application, so I still need to handle the the error there. I will see if I can incorporate the `.retry()` method somehow.

Comment: You can throw it delibrately if you encounter 401, so it will route to the catch block. Observable.throw('401')